# Bind and Unbind Scrolling (using touchmove or difference solution)

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have simple question how i can disable and enable scrolling for a while at mobile device? After quick search i found this

```
  jQuery("body").bind("touchmove",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
  });
```

Works perfectly, but how to enable it again?? I have two function

```
function mobilePopUp()
{
      jQuery("body").bind("touchmove",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
      });  
}
```

and

```
function mobilePopUpClose
{
  // there i want to enable it back
}
```

Is it even posible with binding touchmove event which is returning false? should i bind anything else with touchmove to know what i should unbind? Maybe implement function name idk. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just `unbind` it.

```
function mobilePopUpClose
{
   jQuery("body").unbind("touchmove");
}
```

Comment: thx it works but there another problem (i did not realized that) i need stop scrolling but i need touchmove for some of my element :-/ you answered my question so ill complete it but if you know how to disable only scrolling please let me now

Comment: @user3051762, just ask another question about that and give me the url. Even if I don't know how to solve it, others will help you.